# из данного списка получить массив подряд идущих простых чисел и найти их сумму

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список чисел который я ввожу с экрана, нужно найти наибольшее количество подряд идущих простых чисел в порядке возрастания (отрицательные тоже считаются) и найти их, если этих рядов несколько, считать тот ряд у которого сумма этих простых чисел больше.
вот сам код который я хотел написать

```py
import math 

def isPrime(n):
    return n != 1 and n != 0  and all(n % t for t in range(2, n))

nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
primes = []
maxcount = count = 0

for num in nums:
    if isPrime(num):
        count += 1
        for i in range(len(nums)-1):
            if nums[i] <= nums[i+1]:
                primes.append(num)
    else:
        maxcount = max(count, maxcount)
        count = 0
maxcount = max(count, maxcount)

print(maxcount)
print(sum(primes))
```

сам пытался эти простые числа из списка отправить в массив и найти их сумму, понимаю что глупо, но не могу сравнить элемент списка с последующим
вот пример ввода и вывода:

ввод: `20 -7 -7 -2 0 1 3 5 5 10`

вывод:
`3 13`

тут посчиталось что сумма ряда `3 5 5`  больше чем `-7 -7 -2`, из за этого взяли `3 5 5`

еще один пример
ввод:
`5 -2 -2 10 8` 
вывод:
`2 -4`

Comment: Для начала, простое число - это НАТУРАЛЬНОЕ число, а это 1, 2, 3, ... Отрицательные не могут быть простыми. Для основного, определиться со способом выявления и выделения простых чисел.

Comment: я это понимаю, можно сказать, чтобы по модулю числа были простыми

Comment: Вам нужно найти ряд в порядке *возрастания*, а Вы ищите в порядке *неубывания* (`nums[i] <= nums[i+1]`). Так и задумано?

Comment: а тут есть разница? в любом случае я хотел хоть как то это представить и написать, не могу даже представить что другое тут можно впихнуть вместо этого

Comment: Для начала стоит определиться с точными условиями задачи. Ряд `3 5 5` неубывающий (каждое следующее число больше предыдущего или равно ему). Если нужен возрастающий ряд, тогда можно взять только `3 5` (равные числа брать нельзя). К тому же непонятно, как считать ряды, содержащие отрицательные числа — исключительно по модулю?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры входных-выходных данных, так будет гораздо понятнее. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]

Comment: если числа равные, то тоже считается. В этой программе необязательно, чтобы простое число было натуральным, и отрицательные числа тоже берутся

Comment: если вам нужно найти наибольшее количество подряд идущих простых чисел во введенной последовательности, то как в приведенных примерах получился вывод  `3 13`  и  `2 -4`  ? что-то не очень понятно что в итоге надо сделать. и почему в вас числа 10 и 4 считаются простыми?

Comment: извиняюсь, сам невнимательно написал, там 3 5 5. в выводе 3 13 , тут 3 это наибольшее подряд идущих простых чисел, а 13 это их сумма

Answer (score 0):

если пользоваться встроенными библиотеками не возбраняется, то можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
from itertools import groupby

strn = '20 -7 -7 -2 0 1 3 5 5 10'.split()

def isPrime(n):
    return n != 1 and n != 0  and all(n % t for t in range(2, n))

primes = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(map(int,strn),key=isPrime) if k]
print(primes)  # [[-7, -7, -2], [3, 5, 5]]
res = max(filter(lambda x: x==sorted(x),primes),key=sum,default=[])
print(res)  # [3, 5, 5]

print(len(res),sum(res))  # 3 13
```

Comment: спасибо большое, код работает. Только хотел бы узнать, как работает этот кусок кода  primes = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(map(int,strn),key=isPrime) if k] и res = max(filter(lambda x: x==sorted(x),primes),key=sum,default=[]), не могу понять что за lambda и как оно работает

Comment: Метод  `groupby`  из библиотеки  `itertools`  группирует элементы списка по ключу  `kye`  , здесь это - простота числа.  Один из аргументов функции  `filter`  - функция, которая должна возвращать  `True`  или  `False`  , здесь это делает  `lambda`  функция. У функции  `max`  тоже есть аргумент  `key`  (необязательный).  Подробнее про  `itertools`  и  `lambda`  читайте в документации и учебниках, это довольно обширная тема, тут в двух словах не расскажешь.